# How to break the text in table header when create pdf in php using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf

I am using http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto4.htm to create the pdf file and am almost 99% done with that but i want to break the text in table header column

Right now its showing like this- 
 Frieght Fee

and i want to show like this  - 
Frieght 
 Fee

here is my code which is showing header value

```
$header = array('Site', 'City', 'Prov.', 'Prod.' ,'Cost','Freight Fee');
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this PHP function:

> explode(separator,string)

Read more:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

This function will break the string into an array. You can then do what ever you want with the array.

Example:

```
$str = "Frieght Fee";
$arraystr = explode(" ", $str);

print_r($arraystr);
/* output
Array
(
    [0] => Frieght
    [1] => Fee
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. The easiest would be using the linebreak method, [`$fpdf->Ln()`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/ln.htm) (it takes an integer as an argument to set the height of the line).

**Edit:** Based on how your data is stored and how you seem to want the output formatted you should use a loop. I'll use a for loop as they're easier for beginners.

Using the example from the tutorial you posted, replace:

```
$this->Cell($w,9,$title,1,1,'C',true);
$this->Ln(10);
```

With something like:

```
for ($ i = 0; i < count($header); i++) {
    $this->Cell($w,9,$header[i],1,1,'C',true);
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```

You can also use fpdf's [Multicell()](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm) method, which works with linebreaks (`\n`) in strings, but it's a little more complicated.

Having looked at that tutorial in a bit more depth though - those headers are supposed to be column headers, which is why they're currently arranged horizontally - that tutorial hasn't really been made to output things the way you want them.

Comment: am using array of header here is code $pdf = new PDF();
// Column headings
$header = array('Site', 'City', 'Prov.', 'Prod.' ,'Cost','Freight Fee','Base Price','FET','PFT','PCT','Local','Fuel Price','GST/HST','In Tax Price','QST/PST','Retail Price','Disc Retail','Your Price','Saving Total');
// Data loading
$data = $pdf->LoadData($dataArray); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','b',14);
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->FancyTable($header,$data);  
$pdf->Output();

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect how your data is stored and the updated formatting you gave in your question. I do have to say, however (and I don't mean this to sound rude, so my apologies if it comes across as such), that if you're not yet comfortable enough using PHP to code a loop you should spend a little more time learning the basics before trying to use something like fpdf - it's not really a tool designed for beginners and if you don't know PHP well you're going to face a lot of problems.